# Laravel: Redirect with flash message after submitted form using vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have two components: Index and Create. Both of these components are loaded from different blade files. The problem is I cannot pass flash message as a prop since these are in different files. How to redirect after a submitted form has been created and and receive the flash message in component Index from Create?

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {

        Service::create([
             'name' => $request->get('name'),
             'vendor_id' => $request->get('vendor'),
             'desc' => $request->get('desc'),
             'hours' => $request->get('hours'),
             'price_per_hour' => $request->get('price'),
             'fixed_price' => $request->get('fixed_price'),
             'user_id' => $request->user()->id
         ]);

         if (\request()->wantsJson()) {
            return response()->json([
                 'alert_store' => 'New service added successfully.'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Create component:

```
     if(ok) {
                axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
                    axios.post('/api/services', {
                        name: this.form.name,
                        vendor: this.form.vendor,
                        desc: this.form.desc,
                        hours: this.form.hours,
                        price: this.form.price,
                        fixed_price: this.form.fixed_price,
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        this.alert_store = response.data.alert_store
                        alert(this.alert_store)
                        window.location.href = '/admin/services';
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                });
            }
        },
```

index.vue:

```
import Create from './Create.vue'; 
import Alert from '../Alert.vue';

export default {

    props: ['alert_store'],

    components: {
        Create,
        Alert,
    },

    data(){
        return {
            services: [],
            alert_success: '',
            alert_error: '',

            errors: [],
            success: [],

             form: {
                 name: '',
                 desc: '',
                 hours: '',
                 price_per_hour: '',
                 vendor: '',
                 fixed_price: '',
             },
            selected: null,
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.loadServices()
        this.getStatus()
   },
    methods: {
        loadServices: function(){
            axios.get('/api/getservicedata')
            .then(response => {
                this.services = response.data;
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
        // getStatus(){
        //        axios
        //         .post('/api/services')
        //         .then(response => {
        //             console.log(response.data.alert_store)
        //         });
        // },

        isEditable(service)
        {
            this.form.name = service.name 
            this.form.desc = service.desc 
            this.form.hours = service.hours 
            this.form.price_per_hour = service.price_per_hour
            this.form.vendor = service.vendor.id
            this.form.fixed_price = service.fixed_price
            if(service.isEditing)
            {
                this.selected = service.id

                service.isEditable = false 
            }
            this.$set(service, 'isEditing', true)

        },

        editService(service)
        {
            if(confirm('Are you sure?'))
            {
                axios.post(`/api/services/${service.id}`, {
                    _method: 'patch',
                    name: this.form.name,
                    vendor: this.form.vendor,
                    desc: this.form.desc,
                    hours: this.form.hours,
                    price_per_hour: this.form.price_per_hour,
                    vendor: this.form.vendor,
                    fixed_price: this.form.fixed_price
                })
                .then(response => {
                    this.alert_success = response.data.alert_update
                    this.success.push(Alert)
                    this.loadServices()
                })
               .catch(response => {
                        this.errors.push(Alert)
                        this.alert_error = `Could not edit, ${service.name}, from services!`
                }) 
            } 
        },

        deleteService(service)
        {
            if(confirm('Are you sure?'))
            {
                axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
                    axios.delete(`/api/services/${service.id}`, {
                        __method: 'DELETE'
                        
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        this.alert_success = response.data.alert_delete
                        this.success.push(Alert)
                        this.loadServices()
                    })
                    .catch(response => {
                        this.errors.push(Alert)
                        this.alert_error = `Could not delete, ${service.name}, from services!`
                    })
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass props into `index.vue` component with different ways.
First and properly (on my mind) way is to use session data.

Like:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        Service::create([
             'name' => $request->get('name'),
             'vendor_id' => $request->get('vendor'),
             'desc' => $request->get('desc'),
             'hours' => $request->get('hours'),
             'price_per_hour' => $request->get('price'),
             'fixed_price' => $request->get('fixed_price'),
             'user_id' => $request->user()->id
         ]);

         \request()->session()->put('yourawesomekey','value');

         if (\request()->wantsJson()) {
            return response()->json([
                 'alert_store' => 'New service added successfully.'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

And when you initialize your component in blade file:

```
    ...
    <your-component-name alert_store="{{ session('yourawesomekey', 'default-value') }}" />
    ...
```

`NOTE` Don't forgot to cleanup session data `\request()->session()->forget('yourawesomekey');`

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: where should i delete the session key?